# Drools rule operator matches is not working in Optaplanner 6.2Fiinal

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

I am using Optaplanner 6.2Final version and everything is working fine except the matches operator.
To explain more, this is my rule.

```
rule "TEST REG EXP OPERATOR"
when
    $cheese:Cheese($cheese.type matches "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozarella")
then
    scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, 1);
end
```

The following is the exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" [Error: unable to resolve method: com.app.test.domain.Cheese.$cheese() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... $cheese.type ~= "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozarella" ....}]
```

**Note** : if I removed **$cheese.** declaration in front of **type**, the rule has no issue. This is working fine :

```
$cheese:Cheese($cheese.type == "Buffulo")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that the following throws exception ONLY on the drools core version 6.2.0.Final and 6.3.0.Final after I have done checking on all the version. It is working in the rest of versions.

```
$cheese:Cheese($cheese.type matches "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozarella")
```

Comment: Even if there is nothing evidently wrong with your code, using a variable on the pattern you are currently in to access one of its attributes is not a common pattern (and I don't see any advantage). Have you try this? `$cheese: Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozarella")`

Comment: Yes, it is working if I use $cheese: Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozare‌​lla"). However, i do not understand why it is not able to allow using variable. How can we achieve the following condition? $cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\S*Mozarella")
$cheese2:Cheese($cheese1.name matches "A.*",  id>$cheese1.id)

Comment: If the `name` condition if about the first `Cheese`, then move it to the first pattern:  `$cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla", name matches "A.*") $cheese2:Cheese(id>$cheese1.id)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have this to work:

```
  $cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla")
  $cheese2:Cheese($che‌​ese1.name matches "A.*", id>$cheese1.id)
```

you'll have to use method calls:

```
  $cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla")
  $cheese2:Cheese($che‌​ese1.getName() matches "A.*", id>$cheese1.getId())
```

This assumes you have been following JavaBeans conventions (as you should). But much better would have been to use

```
  $cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla",
                  name matches "A.*", $id1: id )
  $cheese2:Cheese( id > $id1 )
```

Comment: `$cheese1:Cheese(type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla")
  $cheese2:Cheese($che‌​ese1.getName() matches "A.*", id>$cheese1.getId())` throws the same exception actually. Perhaps my question was not clear. The question was why `$cheese1:Cheese($cheese1.type matches "(Buffulo)?\\SMozare‌​lla")` throws exception of using variable and why the following is working fine? `$cheese1:Cheese($cheese1.type == "Buffulo")`

Comment: To answer that, we should know the Drools version and have accurate (!) code for class Cheese. Perhaps you add this to your question. -- But the usual paradigm is to use field names without preceding binding variable and without parentheses, in contrast to a binding variable followed by a dot, the getter name (!) and a pair of parentheses.

Comment: thanks for answer. After i have done checking on other drools versions it seems working. So, it is because I am using 6.2.0.Final version. I updated the post.